# How do I sort a nested array in Swift 5?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nested

`I can't figure out how to sort the people inside of the names.  Any help would be appreciated.

I can't seem to get the reference correct to use sort or sorted

```
import SwiftUI

struct family: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var names: [people]
}
struct people: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
let fam = family(id: 1, names: [people(id: 1, name: "john"),
                              people(id: 2, name: "jane"),
                              people(id: 0, name: "mark"),
                              people(id: 3, name: "joe"),
                              people(id: 4, name: "carol")
                              ])
print(fam.names[0])
print(fam.names[1])
print(fam.names[2])
print(fam.names[3])
print(fam.names[4])
```

I would like to sort by id or name.

Comment: This isn't really a nested array (which usually refers to nesting arrays within arrays). It's just a value stored in a struct. But it's just a value, there's nothing special about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to arrange your names array inside the `fam` object you first need to change it to be `var` declared

```
var fam = family(...
```

Then you can apply `sort(by:)`, below example sorts on name ascending

```
fam.names.sort(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sorted(by:)`

```
fam.names.sorted(by: { $0.id > $1.id })
```

Comment: what if the fam is an array?